# Nested class strange function lookup: surrounding class functions hide global functions

Tags: c++, gcc, argument-dependent-lookup

I have the following simplified code

```
namespace Namespace
{
int foo() { return 1; }

class Class
{
public:
    int foo() const { return 2; }
    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested()
        {
            cout << foo() << endl;
        }
    };
};
}
```

And I got this error:

> error: cannot call member function ‘int Namespace::Class::foo() const’
>   without object:

```
 cout << foo() << endl;
         ^^^^^
```

It seems that compiler selects non static `int Namespace::Class::foo() const` instead of global function `int Namespace::foo()`.

But how can it be expected that non-static function from other class can be called without object? `Nested object` has no access to surrounding  `Class object` - this is not Java after all.

I read carefully through [overload resolution from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) I cannot find the rationale for this behavior. I rather doubt that this is gcc error.

- Can you point the language rules responsible for this behavior?
- And how do you deal with such problems?

### [UPDATE]

Just an answer for 2nd question. Workaround is simple, there is a need to tell compiler that such global function exists:

```
        Nested()
        {
            using Namespace::foo; //< workaround: inform compiler such function exists
            cout << foo() << endl;
        }
```

BTW, is that workaround correct? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: I'm baffled as to why the outer class method is selected instead of the global function. `Namespace::foo()` does however execute the global function.

Comment: Isn't this about overload resolution but rather about name lookup? Like, as the class' `foo` is closer in the namespaces hierarchy, and thus we find this function first and just stop there the lookup? Looking up the standard to confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I read carefully through overload resolution from cppreference I cannot find the rationale for this behavior. Can you point the language rules responsible for this behavior?*

Before the *overload resolution* procedure selects the best viable function, an initial set of candidates is generated during the *name lookup* phase. In other words, the expected behavior should be searched for in the [Name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) section, not in the [Overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) one.

The name lookup procedure for an *unqualified name* is described in the C++ standard:

§3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual]/p8:

> **A name used in the definition of a member function** (9.3) of class `X` following the function’s *declarator-id* or in the *brace-or-equal-initializer* of a non-static data member (9.2) of class `X` **shall be declared in one of the following ways:**
>
> — before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or
>
> — shall be a member of class X or be a member of a base class of X (10.2), or
>
> — **if `X` is a nested class of class `Y` (9.7), shall be a member of `Y`**, or shall be a member of a base class of `Y`
> (this lookup applies in turn to `Y`’s enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class), or [...]

and only if still not found:

> — if `X` is a member of namespace `N`, or **is a nested class of a class that is a member of `N`**, or is a local class or a nested class within a local class of a function that is a member of `N`, before the use of the name, **in namespace `N`** or in one of `N`'s enclosing namespaces.

Since the name lookup ends as soon as the name is found (§3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual]/p1):

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

in your case no other scopes are searched as soon as `int foo() const { return 2; }` is encountered.

---

> *Workaround is simple, there is a need to tell compiler that such global function exists:*
>
> ```
> using Namespace::foo; //< workaround: inform compiler such function exists
> ```
>
> *Is that workaround correct?*

§7.3.3 [namespace.udecl]/p1:

> A *using-declaration* introduces a name into the declarative region in which the *using-declaration* appears.

§3.3.1 [basic.scope.declarative]/p1:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a *declarative region*, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is *valid*, that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the same entity.

Introducing a name with a *using-declaration* impacts the *unqualified name lookup* in a way such that it finds that function in its first step, namely that name becomes *declared*:

> — before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3)

---

> *Are there any better solutions?*

One can use a *qualified name* when referring to a function from some namespace scope, explicitly indicating what symbol is being referred to:

```
Nested()
{
    cout << Namespace::foo() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This was indeed about Name Lookup and not about Overload Resolution.

Indeed, as the standard stipulates, **§3.4.1/1** of N3376 (emphasis mine):

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.** If no declaration is found, the program is ill-formed.

So in fact, the lookup stops as soon as a declaration is found.

Then, you can find more about the case you're dealing with in **§3.4.1/8** which deals with names used in class inside a member function definition, especially this part:

> if X is a nested class of class Y (9.7), shall be a member of Y, or shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies in turn to Y’s enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class)

And if not found, in enclosing namespaces.

In your case, that means that `Namespace::Class::foo()` is the first name found during the lookup, and it stops as soon as it has found a name, so `Namespace::foo()` isn't even considered.

The example given by the standard illustrates the lookup path:

```
class B { };
namespace M {
    namespace N {
        class X : public B {
            void f(); 
        };
    } 
}
void M::N::X::f() {
    i = 16;
}
```

> The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:
>
> 1) outermost block scope of M::N::X::f, before the use of i // 2) scope of class M::N::X
>
> 3) scope of M::N::X’s base class B
>
> 4) scope of namespace M::N
>
> 5) scope of namespace M
>
> 6) global scope, before the definition of M::N::X::f

And as to how you deal with such problem, you have to qualify the call, i.e.

```
cout << Namespace::foo() << endl;
```

so that the compiler selects the function you want through qualified lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Piotr S. and JBL explained the why of your problem.

IMHO the simpler solution is to use the qualified name of the function :

```
public:
    Nested()
    {
        cout << Namespace::foo() << endl;
    }
```